# Dynamic Class identifier based on variable

Tags: c#, class, dynamic

I have the following function below that I'm trying to make and fill a class called User.

I want the Class Identifier to be dynamically named for each user there is.

The datatable that is being passed in contains informations like below.

```
USER     | CONTROLNUMBER
"jsmith" | "789842"
```

I want to make a class named "JSmith" and fill the properties in that class accordingly.

I am extremely new to using classes in useful way, so be gentle.

```
public static void FillUserListClass(DataTable dt, string _userName)
{
User _userName = new User();
_userName.ControlNumber = "789842";
_userName.UserName = "jsmith";
}
```

Comment: That's not a useful way of using classes. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: think about the word 'class' John Smith is not a class, unless there are lots of them (which I guess there is but that's not the point!) User is a class of object/entity and jsmith is classed as a user. so what you are doing in that code snippet is correct.

Comment: I'm trying to keep track of all of the ControlNumbers that my program selects (function not shown). I would like to keep track of the name associated with each ControlNumber as well.. I've thought about using a Dictionary but that seems limited since I will have 1 UserName and potentially thousands of ControlNumbers for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be right for the dictionary of list idea?

```
static Dictionary<string, List<int>> UserList = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

public static void FillUserListClass(DataTable dt)
{
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < dt.Rows.Count; ctr++)
                {
                    var row = dt.Rows[ctr];
                    var userName = row["User"].ToString();

                    if (UserList.ContainsKey(userName))
                    {
                        UserList[userName].Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UserList.Add(row["User"].ToString(), new List<int>());
                        UserList[userName].Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
                    }
    }
```

And if so, how would i print out the dictionary so you would see something similar to

```
'jsmith' has 4 control numbers.

"234950"
"494602"
"494200"
"585890"
```

Comment: yep! thats the idea!  to print, just do a `foreach(var kvp in UserList)` then kvp (or keyValuePair) will have a key member, thats the user name, and a value member thats the list of numbers